# Multiple question on same movie at a time should be in one  single question or in separate one?

Tags: discussion

I watched  these three([1](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/in-mission-impossible-1-why-didnt-phelps-kill-ethan-as-easily-as-his-wife),[2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-does-ethan-know-that-phelps-is-the-mole),[3](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2439/what-was-the-salary-of-an-imf-agent)) question from same user about Mission Impossible posted one by one seperately.

My question is that is it good to place multiple question on same topic in same question or is it good to post them seperately?

Comment: I wonder why this question was downvoted. It is pretty essential for a Q&A site to discuss this kind of stuff. Many questions in one post generally does not work too well.

Comment: @GertArnold. the down vote was not me, but on meta a down vote means disagreement, not that it was a bad question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking unless the questions are closely related, then they should be posted separately.  By closely related I do not mean 'about the same movie', I mean that the questions are linked such as answer to the first question may impacts the answer to the second.

The questions here are not particularly related, the salary of an IMF agent is not related to why Phelps did not kill Ethan on the train - so they clearly should not be posted together.

Asking any number of questions on the same movie in separate posts is completely fine.

Comment: Caveat: as long as they are **quality** questions.  IE, not posted to create spam that'll get closed.  Otherwise yeah, feel free to post seperate questions

Comment: except for the salary question the other two can be joined together

Comment: @AnkitSharma. I disagree. How does Ethan know Phelps is the mole has nothing to do with why Phelps does not kill Ethan on the train.